# asterisk events in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, event-handling, asterisk

I'm developing a contact management system with Codeigniter framework (php-jquery) and I'm using Asterisk (11 or higher) to manage calls.

In this system, there are both incoming and outgoing calls. In case of outgoing calls, I want to call someone by clicking a button and in case of incoming calls, I want to show them as notification popup whenever that happens. For this purpose, I'm writing a library class as follows which only manages outgoing calls.

```
class Asterisk {
public $server;
public $port;
public $socket;
public $error;
const NOSOCKET      = 'No Socket Defined';
const CONNECTFAILED = 'Connection Failed';
const AUTHFAIL      = 'Authentication Failed';
const NORESP        = 'Server Didn\'t Respond';

public function __construct($params = array()) {

    $this->server = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $this->port = 5038;

    if (isset($params['server']))
        $this->server = $params['server'];
    if (isset($params['port'])) {
        $this->port = $params['port'];
    }
}

private function _check() {
    if ($this->socket)
        return true;

    $this->error = Asterisk::NOSOCKET;
    redirect('');
}

private function _command($query, $expect = null, $error = null) {
    $this->_check();

    fputs($this->socket, $query."\r\n");
    $response = fgets($this->socket);

    if (!$response) {
        $this->error = Asterisk::NORESP;
        return false;
    }

    if ($expect == null)
        return true;

    if (strpos($response, $expect) != false)
        return true;

    $this->error = $error;
    return false;
}

/* ************************************************************************************************************** */

public function connect($server = null, $port = null) {
    if ($this->socket)
        $this->close();

    if ($server != null && $port != null) {
        $this->server = $server;
        $this->port = $port;
    }

    $this->socket = fsockopen($this->server, $this->port, $errno, $errstr, 1);
    if (!$this->socket) {
        $this->error =  Asterisk::CONNECTFAILED . " - $errstr ($errno)";
        return false;
    }

    stream_set_timeout($this->socket, 3);
    return true;
}

public function close() {
    $this->_check();

    fclose($this->socket);
    return true;
}

public function login($username, $password) {
    return $this->_command(
        "Action: Login\r\n".
        "UserName: $username\r\n".
        "Secret: $password\r\n".
        "Events: off\r\n",
        "Message: Authentication accepted",
        Asterisk::AUTHFAIL
    );
}

public function logout() {
    return $this->_command(
        "Action: Logoff\r\n"
    );
}

/* ************************************************************************************************************** */

public function call($channel, $context, $extension, $callerId, $priority = 1, $async = true, $timeout = 30000) {
    return $this->_command(
        "Action: Originate\r\n".
        "Channel: $channel\r\n".
        "Context: $context\r\n".
        "Exten: $extension\r\n".
        "Priority: $priority\r\n".
        "Async: $async\r\n".
        "CallerId: $callerId\r\n".
        "TimeOut: $timeout\r\n"
    );
}
}
```

How can I update this class to handle incoming calls and their events?

I know there are some existing libraries like [PAMI](https://github.com/marcelog/PAMI) but it does not work with codeigniter and mvc model properly.

how can i manage these incoming calls? Can someone post some example code?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this in a few implementations, using PHP and Laravel as well as PAMI (and PAGI for booting customized AGI interactions).

In short: The stream of AMI events requires active listening to a series of events and parsing data from the stream. To get a handle on the stream, I've always created a small separate program (in PHP with PAGI), which handles the stream of events and sends events back to the host application via WebSocket (using HOA Websocket on both ends).

The reasons for this approach is:

- Allows a small and lightweight program to do the job of listening for all AMI events.
- Decouple a 'real-time' system from a web application, and talk to the web application in a manner commensurate to the way a web application is used to being talked
- Unblock the consumption of events streaming from AMI, since you onloy have to see the event, and send a message across a socket connection without acknowledging response.
- Use a great library, like PAMI, to deal with AMI and share a lib of custom DTOs so that mapping AMI raw info to application-specific DTOs only happens on the AMI consumer program, and my other applications don't have to have knowledge of AMI.
- Most importantly: the run time configurations for PHP as a web application will most likely be very different from the configuration of a program meant to consume live streams of events. If you miss an event, you will not get it again!

Once set up with a AMI gateway program, which takes events and passes them to the main application, you can then use the AMI gateway program to send instructions to Asterisk (Actions) and you will already have a means of handling the response from the action.